# Reading in a range using a named cell reference and a variable

Tags: vba, excel

I wish to read in a range that is based using a named cell reference.

The named cell reference is "AggStatsStart" and refers to AggOutput!$A$2

I also have a integer variable called "NoCohort" = 1000.

I want to use the two variables to read in the range C3:Q1000. Note the offset from AggStatsStart

So far I have the following:

```
Dim testRange As Range
Dim Input As Variant
With Sheets("AggOutput")
    Set testRange = .Range("AggStatsStart", .Cells(NoCohort, 15))
End With
Input = Range(testRange)
```

Comment: Should the Q reference be an offset from the AggStatsStart range too? In other words do you always want 15 columns, starting 2 to the right of the range, or is Q fixed?

Comment: What do you want to do with this range? When I tested the code, It work well. I tested this code `MsgBox .Range("AggStatsStart", .Cells(NoCohort, 15)).Count` which is getting all cell count from that range. It is Ok. Tell me more. What is your requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fixing several small syntax errors:

```
Sub BenWhite()
    Dim testRange As Range
    Dim Inputt As Variant
    Dim NoCohort As Integer
    NoCohort = 1000

    With Sheets("AggOutput")
        Set testRange = .Range(Range("AggStatsStart"), .Cells(NoCohort, 15))
        MsgBox testRange.Address(0, 0)
    End With

    Inputt = testRange
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: added             Set testRange = .Range(Range("AggStatsStart").Offset(1, 2), .Cells(NoCohort, 15)) to include the offset from the start range.